# Adding a new custom Customer attribute when updating a module

Tags: php, magento, magento2, magento2.2

I'm having troubles at creating new customer attribute when upgrading one of my modules.

I've created the UpgradeData.php file under `/app/code/vendor/modulename/Setup/UpgradeData.php` with the current code:

```
namespace Ucs\CustomerAttribute\Setup;
use Magento\Customer\Model\Customer;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory;
class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface{

private $customerSetupFactory;

public function __construct(
    CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory
) {
    $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
}

/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context){

    $setup->startSetup();

    $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

    if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'nome_azienda', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Nome azienda',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'nome_azienda')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();


        $customerSetup->addAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'codice_univoco', [
            'type' => 'varchar',
            'label' => 'Codice Univoco',
            'input' => 'text',
            'source' => '',
            'required' => false,
            'visible' => true,
            'position' => 333,
            'system' => false,
            'backend' => ''
        ]);

        $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'codice_univoco')
            ->addData(['used_in_forms' => [
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'adminhtml_checkout',
                'customer_account_create',
                'customer_account_edit'
            ]]);
        $attribute->save();


    }
}
}
```

in short, it needs to create 2 new text (varchar) attributes. My `module.xml` has 
`setup_version="1.0.5"  schema_version="1.0.5"` so it should enter the `version_compare` condition and create the attribute, but, after running `php bin/magento setup:upgrade` it doesn't work. If i check in the `setup_module` table, the `setup_version` and `schema_version` change correctly with the version in the `module.xml`. It looks like for some reason the `UpgradeData.php` does not get executed at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Ucs\CustomerAttribute\etc\module.xml
change version to 1.0.6

then replace

`if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6') < 0) {`

with

`if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.6', '<')) {`

Edit: Just to be sure.. by

> I've created the UpgradeData.php file under
>   /app/code/vendor/modulename/Setup/UpgradeData.php

You mean app/code/Ucs/CustomerAttribute/Setup/UpgradeData.php ?

Edit2:

I assumed Your agency is called Ucs. That's why I've asked about it, beacuse that's what suggest Your module namespace. 
This is not recomended practice but for purpose of installator verification, change namespace to:
namespace vendor\modulename\Setup;

What I recomend is:

1. Create a new module or find app/code/[YOURCOMPANYNAME]/Customer - try to corespond Magento native modules. This way You can easier manage code, design and Magento doesn't need to load separated module for each functionallity.
2. In UpgradeData.php try to call separate function for each version.
   Like:

```
     if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {
                $this->addCustomerMyAttribute();
            }
     $setup->endSetup();
```

and then below

```
 private function addCustomerMyAttribute($setup){
// Your code goes here

}
```

If it's first version of Customer module in app/code/[YOURCOMPANYNAME] remember to create InstallData.php insted of UpgradeData.php (in that case no need to check version).

3. After `bin/magento setup:upgrade` check `eav_attribute` table for new attribute.
4. If it's there remember to bin/magento indexer:reindex so it goes to flat table. If it's not there. Put ```die(var_dump('I'm running'); at the beginning of `upgrade` function.

Comment: Tried changing the 'if', nothing changed (ofc also changing the setup_version and schema_version in the module.xml. Even by removing the 'if' statement nothing changes

As for the position of the UpgradeData.php file it's in app/code/vendor/modulename/Setup/UpgradeData.php since i'm trying to update my module, of course the naming is not Ucs/CustomerAttribute/

Comment: I managed to do it without creating a new module from scratch. In the database, from the setup_module tab i deleted the row of this module, added the new attributes declaration in the InstallData.php file and run `bin/magento setup:upgrade`, not the best solution since for some reason it still doesn't execute the UpgradeData.php script (even after fixing the mistake in the namespace) but at least it works! 
I'm adding your answer as solution since the suggestion to create a new module will work 100%